# Magento2 creating and calling modal widget

Tags: magento-2.1, modal-popup

I want to create custom modal popup widget and call on my `.phtml` file. How can I do that?

What will be the whole procedure for creating modal and accessing it from the `.phtml` file?

Comment: Check the link, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-create-popup-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should create a module first, then after create a `requirejs-config.js` file at `app/code/Vendor/YourModule/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
         'myjs': "Vendor_YourModule/js/myfile"
      },   
    shim: {
    'myjs': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
  }
}
```

You need to create `myfile.js` in `app/code/Vendor/YourModule/view/frontend/web/js/myfile.js`

```
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: 'mymodal1',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
            $("#click-me").on('click',function(){
                $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
            });
        }
    );
```

Then your phtml file should look like:

```
<div data-mage-init='{"myjs": {}}'>
    <a href="#" id="click-me">Click Me</a>
</div>


<div id="popup-modal" >
    yes I am the modal.
</div>
```

Comment: Worked Perfect! All the options that can be passed to the modal can be found here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html

Comment: how to add resize and draggable facility in it.

Comment: Before starting to this I just want to confirm, Is this popup will dynamic data.

Comment: Is there a way to pass data from PHP into the script?

Comment: The modal applies "overlay: hidden" to the body and this removes the scrollbar as well. How can I replace this behavior with something like "document.addEventListener('wheel', preventScroll, { passive: false })" which prevent just the scrolling?

Answer (score 15):

You just need to add a container for the modal `<div id="popup-modal"></div>` and a small bit of javascript to initialise the modal like below:

```
<div id="popup-modal"><p>Hello World</p></div>

<script>
require(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
],
function(
    $,
    modal
) {
    let options = {
        type: 'popup',
        responsive: true,
        innerScroll: true,
        title: 'Modal Title',
        modalClass: 'custom-modal',
        buttons: [{
            text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
            class: '',
            click: function () {
                this.closeModal();
            }
        }]
    };
    
    let $myModal = $('#popup-modal');
    let popup = modal(options, $myModal);
    
    //this opens the modal, you can use some click event or whatever you need to trigger the modal here
    $myModal.modal('openModal');
});
</script>
```

So the `$myModal.modal('openModal');` will trigger the popup instantly however could be used like below to maybe trigger when clicking a button or link for example:

```
$(".open-modal").click(function() {
    $myModal.modal('openModal');
});
```

Comment: How can i call the same model from external javascript file?

Comment: Just take that script out and add externally it will work the same.

Comment: I have tried the same,  I placed my js file in web\js of my module also I have included the header tag in my layout.xml but cant access the modal. where I am wrong can you tell?

Comment: Well i would first check that you can see your JS loaded in the page. Check that your modal markup present also. Then check for and errors in your console.

Comment: When I do "view page source" the file is included but on console it is giving error "404"

Comment: Seems like the JS file is not in the right place show how you have included the JS file and its path.

Comment: on my layout.xml   <head>
 <script src="moduleName::js/myjs.js" />
 </head>

Comment: Yeah you can add them like other than moduleName should be vendor_ModuleName.

Comment: yeah I have defined it in the same way

Comment: I can access other functions from that file but not the modal

Comment: So what file is the 404 for?

Answer (score 5):

I have used this, hope this will help you

```
 <button type="button" class="action" data-trigger="trigger">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Click Here'"></span>
</button>
<div data-bind="mageInit: {
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal':{
            'type': 'popup',
            'title': 'Popup title',
            'trigger': '[data-trigger=trigger]',
            'responsive': true,
            'buttons': [{
                text: 'Submit',
                class: 'action'
            }]
        }}">
    <div class="content">
        Popup Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How I can make this popup dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Took the example from Magento 2.4 documentation, and modified slightly to hide the "click me!" opener link until the modal code has finished loading. Without this, there can be several seconds during page load where clicking the opener link does nothing.

Just add the below to your .phtml - you can refactor the inline style and script to separate files if you wish.

See here for more modal/popup examples and options:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html

```
<style>
#modal-promo, #modal-promo-opener {display: none}
</style>

<a href="#" id="modal-promo-opener">
    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Click me')) ?></span>
</a>

<div id="modal-promo">
    <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <p><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Modal content here...')) ?></p>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "jquery",
        "Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal"
    ],function($, modal) {

        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            buttons: []
        };

        var $modal = $('#modal-promo'), $opener = $('#modal-promo-opener');

        var popup = modal(options, $modal);
        $opener.click(function() {
            $modal.modal('openModal');
        });

        $opener.show();

    });
</script>
```