# Newsletter popup only showing clossing button

Tags: magento2.3, newsletter-block

In my theme settings having enable newsletter pop-up option, i enable it. But showing light grey-out colour and clossing button only, not getting newsletter form.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please share your live url ? or theme name?

Comment: I'm using Fastest theme

Comment: please check console, does it have any errors?

Comment: Yeah, i checked i did not get any error

Comment: need more information...Did you override any files of themes?

Comment: Yeah, i override in my child theme only, but not yet touch in newsletter folder

Comment: Then i think the newsletter is managed from cms block....if so can u pls check in this case/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91438/discussion-between-mohana-and-ranganathan).

Answer (score 1):

Please can you Provide your code Here Right Now, Otherwise Please Prefer This link to get more info about popup model in magento :-

> [Magento2 creating and calling modal widget](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208259/magento2-creating-and-calling-modal-widget)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I got the result by adding  static block and place the id in popup newsletter box.