# How to create a popup model in magento 2

Tags: magento2, popup

How to create a popup model in magento 2

when click a custom "add to quote" button i need a popup model like  with  product details

Expected like:

[image: 22]

Answer (score 0):

In magento Modal is a widget and you need to initiate it in JS rest is all the same as simple Bootstrap HTML modal i.e you can add your content as you want.
You can see [these](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html) [links](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208259/magento2-creating-and-calling-modal-widget).